# Direct image of a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\cal{A}$) and $(X',\cal{A}')$ be two measurable spaces and $T:X\to X'$ a bijective measurable map.

The claim is that $T(\cal{A})$ is a sigma algebra on $X' \iff T^{-1}:X'\to X$ is measurable.

I may have probably worked out the "$\impliedby$" direction. For the "$\implies$" direction I am not too sure, any hints would be nice.

Maybe the claim above is false. I would still like to know under what circumstances $T(\cal{A})$ will be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X'$ !

Comment: You write $T^{-1}$ down as if $T$ were invertible. I guess you mean something else ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will edit it so that $T$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra on $X$, and $T:X\to X'$ is any map whatsoever,
then $T(\mathcal{A})$, consisting of those sets $E\subset X'$ such that $T^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{A}$, is a sigma-algebra on $X'$. (See for example Proposition 3.1.1 of Resnick's A Probability Path).

The map $T$ is measurable provided that $\mathcal{A'}\subset T(\mathcal{A})$. This just restates the definition of measurability.

I don't think much more can be said in general.